# angularfire2 cant find module '@angular/fire'

Tags: firebase, angularfire2

1. app.components.ts:

> import { AngularFireModule } from '@angular/fire';   import {
>   AngularFirestore } from 'angularire2/firestore';
>
> @NgModule
>    ({   declarations: [
>       AppComponent,
>       SignupComponent,
>       LandingComponent,
>       ProfileComponent,
>       NavbarComponent,
>       FooterComponent,
>       LoginComponent,
>       BlogComponent,
>       ForgetpwdComponent,
>       BlogDashboartComponent,
>       BlogDetailsComponent,
>       BlogListComponent   ],
>    imports: [
>       BrowserModule,
>       NgbModule.forRoot(),
>       FormsModule,
>       RouterModule,
>       AppRoutingModule,
>       HomeModule,
>       ReactiveFormsModule,
>      HttpModule],
>   providers: [AngularFirestore ],
>   bootstrap: [AppComponent] })

The imports that doesnt work located in a service:

> import { Posts } from './posts';
>   import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
>   import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from 'angularfire2/firestore';
>   import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

I only included the dependencies that may have something to do with the error but if i missed something please tell me.

Comment: What version of angularfire you are using?

Comment: Angular CLI: 8.2.2